# Unexpected conversion Xml to DataSet

Tags: c#, serialization, dataset

I have a class Car

```
[Serializable]
public class Car
{
    public Driver Driver = new Driver();
    public List<Driver> Drivers = new List<Driver>();
}

[Serializable]
public class Driver
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to serialize an isntance of this class and then convert to DataSet I get a realyy strange behaviour:

```
void Main()
{
    var x = new Car();
    x.Drivers.Add(new Driver { Id = 1 });
    var dataSet= AsDataSet(x);
    dataSet.Tables["Driver"].Rows.Count;//2!! and two columns: Id and Driver_Id
    dataSet.Tables["Drivers"].Rows.Count;//1    and only one column Driver_Id
}

static DataSet AsDataSet(Car ceInv)
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(ceInv.GetType());
    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    serializer.Serialize(ms, ceInv);
    ms.Position = 0;
    var ds = new DataSet();
    ds.ReadXml(ms);
    return ds;
}
```

Could someone tell me why the table Drivers is empty and without the column Id?
Unfortunately the property Driver should stay like this (legacy code). I can only change the property Drivers.
Changing the name of the property Drivers has no impact on the result.

Comment: Trying to run it, but don't have the definition of `Dump()`

Comment: Kind of inferred from usage what `Dump()` should look like. Looking into it now

Comment: sorry, it's a function from linqpad. I'll correct the code

Answer (score 0):

Look at the serialized representation of your `DataSet` and it should be obvious.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Car xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Driver>
    <Id>0</Id>
  </Driver>
  <Drivers>
    <Driver>
      <Id>1</Id>
    </Driver>
  </Drivers>
</Car>
```

How do you expect the `ReadXml()` method to distinguish between the first `<Driver>` element and the the elements within the `<Drivers>` element? They appear to be part of the same table.

You are also instantiating a new `Driver` in your `Car` class with a null `Id`, not sure if that was intentional.

In any case, I would make your property names less ambiguous so that `ReadXml()` can sort things out. For example, change the single `Driver` property in `Car` to be `PrimaryDriver` or similar.

I know you said you can't change that property, so the only solution would be a custom XML serializer, but that may not get you the `DataSet` you need.

```
void Main()
{
    var x = new Car();
    x.Drivers.Add(new Driver { Id = 1 });
    var dataSet = AsDataSet(x);
    Console.WriteLine($"PrimaryDriver: {dataSet.Tables["PrimaryDriver"].Rows.Count}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Drivers: {dataSet.Tables["Drivers"].Rows.Count}");

    // Output:
    // PrimaryDriver: 1
    // Drivers: 1
}

[Serializable]
public class Car
{
    public Driver PrimaryDriver = new Driver();
    public List<Driver> Drivers = new List<Driver>();
}

[Serializable]
public class Driver
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

private static DataSet AsDataSet(Car ceInv)
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(ceInv.GetType());
    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    serializer.Serialize(ms, ceInv);
    ms.Position = 0;
    var ds = new DataSet();
    //Console.WriteLine($"{new StreamReader(ms).ReadToEnd()}"); ms.Position = 0; // DEBUGGING
    ds.ReadXml(ms);
    return ds;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I've seen after renaming one/both properties in your `Car` class, it seems that `ReadXml()` infers the schema based on the types in use and not just the properties. Consider the following; after changing the definition of `Car` to

```
[Serializable]
public class Car
{
    public Driver Someone { get; set; } = new Driver { Id = 47 }; // I did this so I could identify the rows
    public List<Driver> Dudes { get; set; } = new List<Driver>(); 
}
```

I ended up with 3 tables in the dataset. Someone, Dudes, and Driver. The individual property is stored as expected in a table named for the property. The list property on the other hand results in the creation of a table named for the type, in this case `Driver` and another named for the property `Drivers` in your case, and `Dudes` in mine.

The data for the `List<Driver>` property is stored in the Driver table. There is a relation between that and the table named after the property.